# How can I share my router's Internet connection over Wi-Fi without giving guests access to my network?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have a network run on a Netgear RangeMax WPN824v3 with wireless access secured with WPA-PSK [TKIP]. I would like to share the Internet connection with guests over Wi-Fi but not give them access to the other computers on my network (or, obviously, my router's passphrase). Some of the newer Netgear routers have this ability. Is there a low-hassle way to do this on my router?

Comment: I would recommend using AES over TKIP due to less overhead and it's more secure. I would recommend doing further research to determine which is better for you.

Comment: Don't see how you can have a passphrase for the home network and leave it open for visitors. Not familiar with that router, but if you set fixed IP addresses for your network devices and set a DHCP range for visitors you should be able to filter traffic with a firewall hased on a subnet mask.

Answer (score 2):

Use a second router, give the router a different IP than the default it comes with, this way your guest will be on their own network, have internet access, and cannot access your network on the other router. Be sure the second router is using a different wireless channel than the first router.

Answer (score 2):

try Multi-SSID technology. for example, one SSID for coworkers, second SSID for guests (with different vlans)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using one of your computers (Windows 7) that has both wired and wireless capabilities to provide internet for your guests.

Use ethernet for incoming internet on the computer and then installing **[Connectify](http://connectify.me/)** or **[Virtual Router](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/)** which creates a virtual WIFI hotspot.  This way, they have their own private network, and they can't interfere with your other computers or your router's passphrase, as you have created a *separate network* for them.